# Flutter Firebase crashes on iOS

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase

I have a Flutter app with Firebase as the Backend. I tried to create a dev and prod environment for my app with a Firebase dev and prod project according to this article: https://kmtsandeepanie.medium.com/set-up-multiple-firebase-environments-in-flutter-9f88bc284454

Everything seems to be correct and the app builds on iOS, except that it crashes on launch without an error in the debug console in Android Studio:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 14 Pro Max in debug mode...
Running pod install...                                             13.5s
Upgrading Pods-Runner-frameworks.sh
Running Xcode build...                                                  
 └─Compiling, linking and signing...                         9.8s
Xcode build done.                                           39.8s
[VERBOSE-2:FlutterDarwinContextMetalImpeller.mm(37)] Using the Impeller rendering backend.
Lost connection to device.
Syncing files to device iPhone 14 Pro Max...                       200ms
```

After the crash I get the following stack trace:

```
Last Exception Backtrace:

0   CoreFoundation                         0x180437324 __exceptionPreprocess + 160    
1   libobjc.A.dylib                        0x180051274 objc_exception_throw + 56   
2   CoreFoundation                         0x180437240 -[NSException initWithCoder:] + 0    
3   FirebaseCore                           0x1034d06d8 +[FIRApp configureWithName:options:] + 284 (FIRApp.m:172)    
4   Runner                                 0x102fac0d4 -[FLTFirebaseCorePlugin initializeAppAppName:initializeAppRequest:completion:] + 1320   
5   Runner                                 0x102fae5b4 __FirebaseCoreHostApiSetup_block_invoke + 192    
6   Flutter                                0x10b8a2b0c __48-[FlutterBasicMessageChannel setMessageHandler:]_block_invoke + 168    
7   Flutter                                0x10b2cc234 invocation function for block in flutter::PlatformMessageHandlerIos::HandlePlatformMessage(std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::unique_ptr<flutter::PlatformMessage, std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::default_delete<flutter::PlatformMessage>>) + 108
```

I had Firebase successfully implemented before switching to the dev/prod environments.
Any ideas what that error is?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A guess is the issue is in how Firebase is initialized. However, some troubleshooting may lead to a more definitive answer. Add a breakpoint early in your code and step through it line by line, inspecting the vars and code execution until it crashes. Then update the question with that code and the line it crashed on. Please take a moment and review [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [No Images Please](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: It's worth checking if the config files match. If you are running the app in the dev environment, did you check if the Firebase config file in your project is referencing to the dev environment? A good spot to check is the path in the build phases 'Copy Bundle and Resources' section of Xcode.

Comment: Thanks for the replies! I edited my question to be more in line with the examples!

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem:

I set the "name" property on "initializeApp":

```
if (env == 'prod') {
    await Firebase.initializeApp(
      name: 'com.example.prod',
      options: ProdFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
    );
} else {
    await Firebase.initializeApp(
      name: 'com.example.dev',
      options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
    );
}
```

This worked fine on Android, but seems to crash iOS in some cases.